# Transform CRS LiDAR point clouds in lidR

Tags: r, lidar, lidr

Is there a way to change the projection (like `st_transform` from `sf`  package) of LiDAR point cloud while remaining in R?

With `lidR` package you can set but not modify the point cloud projection. I know las2las from lastools could do the job (and this part is open) but I would like to keep it simple, within R and without hard copying the input/output of this process.

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question has already been answered on [gis.stackexchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/371566/can-i-re-project-an-las-file-in-lidr). In short you can use `spTransform` on a LAS object but it is recommended to used `las2las`

```r
library(lidR)
LASfile <- system.file("extdata", "Megaplot.laz", package="lidR")
las <- readLAS(LASfile)
las2 <- spTransform(las, sp::CRS(SRS_string = "EPSG:26918"))
```